# HiLo generator strategy not working

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, hibernate-annotations

I am new to hibernate. What I am trying to do is use `@CollectionId`to generate an identifier for my Address class. I have used `Collection` interface for this. However when I use `@GenericGenerator` and set strategy to hilo, it throws an Exception.
Here's my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="USER_ADDRESS",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    )

    @GenericGenerator(name = "hilo-gen", strategy = "hilo")
    @CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID") }, generator = "hilo-gen", type = @Type(type="long"))
    private Collection<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Collection<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=null]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.<init>(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.<init>(BasicCollectionPersister.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.hbt.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Support for 'hilo' generator has been removed
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.getIdentifierGeneratorClass(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:112)
    ... 14 more
```

I am using the latest hibernate. What should I do?

Comment: Also I am using MySql as my database

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hilo is not supported anymore, this should work

```
@GenericGenerator(name="sequence-gen",strategy="sequence")
```

Comment: can you explain the reason for the removal of `halo`

Answer (score 12):

If we are using mysql it would be better to use the **@GenericGenerator** of **increment** strategy.

1. **sequence** - This sort of strategy supports by Oracle, Postgresql.
2. **increment** - This sort of strategy supports by MySql.

   ```
   @ElementCollection
   @JoinTable(name="USER_ADDRESS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"))
   @GenericGenerator(name = "increment-gen", strategy = "increment")
   @CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID") }, generator = "increment-gen", type = @Type(type="long"))
   private Collection<Address> listOfAddress = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

When  I have used the **sequence** strategy with MySql I came across an issue where my **ADDRESS_ID**
is not getting incremented properly.

[image: SEQUENCE_STRATEGY_ISSUE]

Comment: Thanks for this information it is quit helpful, i too was getting the error but not the above one, my code refused to compile with below error-
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists sequence-gen" via JDBC Statement.
But modifying strategy to increment resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Support for **'hilo'** generator has been removed. For additional information, this link gives you the deprecated list.

To overcome this, you can simply use **sequence generator**. This will solve your problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="USER_ADDRESS",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    )

    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence-gen", strategy = "sequence")
    @CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID") }, generator = "sequence-gen", type = @Type(type="long"))
    private Collection<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Collection<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, MYSQL supports sequence strategy however table name should not contain hyphen '-' (which is name provided in @GenericGenerator(name) 
could cause DDL exception while creating sequence table in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for apps on PostgreSQL. Though I have not tested it, it should work for all DBs. Note that `increment-gen` is used not sequence.

```
@ElementCollection
    @JoinTable( name = "user_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "user_id"))
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment-gen",strategy="increment")
    @CollectionId( columns = { @Column( name ="address_id") }, generator ="increment-gen", type =@Type( type ="long"))
    private Collection<Address> listOfAddresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must choose from one of the Hi/Lo strategy :

- **[SequenceHiLoGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/SequenceHiLoGenerator.html)** : to back the Hi with a Sequence
- **[MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.html)** : to back the Hi with a Table

To be as close as your tutorial as possible, I would simply change "hilo" to "seqhilo" in your code.

Comment: Has there been any change in latest hibernate? Coz the tutorial I am following uses hibernate 3.0. And I am using hibernate 5.0. Does the latest version not support hilo?

Comment: I do not know when they made the change, but from what I know you should use one of the above strategy. To be as close as your tutorial as possible, I would simply change "hilo" into "seqhilo"

Comment: @AdityaSawant Support for 'hilo' generator has been removed

Comment: @kommradHomer what is the reason for the removal?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya i have no idea. But as far as i remember , they just replaced the way it's implemented or used. So you can still have the functionality , if you adjust your code properly

Comment: @kommradHomer Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try **any of the below 2 solutions** and it will fix your issue. it is as per the specification provided in **Hibernate 5.2.X.**

Source Of Info -https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

**Solution 1 -**

```
 @GenericGenerator(name = "product_generator",strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator")
 @CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID") }, generator = "product_generator", type = @Type(type="long"))*
```

**Solution 2 -**

```
*@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "product_generator")
 @CollectionId(columns = { @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID") }, generator = "product_generator", type = @Type(type="long"))*
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Can you explain what is the source of the problem and how your three lines fix it?

Comment: The source of the problem is Aditya Sawant was trying to use Hilo strategy in hibernate. Which is deprecated in newer versions of hibernate. My 2 solution advises on how to achieve the same goal using the Generic Generator of SEQUENCE type.